# Canvas stroke() does not draw at edge of clip

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

I've created a slide show with canvas, and I'm using a clip to round the edges of the images in it. Because the clip does not fade out, I stroke the clip path before calling clip() to smooth the outer edges, then stroke it again after drawing an image to smooth the inner edges. This worked flawlessly in chrome, but testing in safari or internet explorer led to the problems shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnGMa.jpg).
The image on the left is chrome, the image on the right is safari. Notice the gap between the line and the edge of the image.

The path that I stroke is the exact same path as the clip path, and the lineWidth is 5, but it looks like safari is not filling in the pixels right at the border of the clip. Is there a way I can fix this without creating an overlay image with the outline?

EDIT 2: I tried removing the clip with restore(), drawing the outline, and reclipping. This works on internet explorer, and sort-of works on safari, but on safari the stroke overwrites the image data instead of blending with it when using this method.

```
var canvas;
var ctx;

function loadSlideshow() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("slideshow"); //Width=960, Height=540
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeStyle="#0d0d0d";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 54);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(480, -27, 960, 54);
    ctx.lineTo(960, 540 - 54);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(480, 540 + 27, 0, 540 - 54);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke(); //Stroke clip path before clipping to outer clip transition
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clip(); //Set clip to make images curved at the top and bottom
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    var imagesToLoad = [
        "images/slideshow/img1.png",
        "images/slideshow/img2.png",
        "images/slideshow/img3.png",
        "images/slideshow/img4.png",
    ]
    for(var i = 0; i < imagesToLoad.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imagesToLoad[i];
        images.push(img);
    }
    images[0].onload = function() {
        requestAnimFrame(animate);
    }
}

var images = [];
var curImage = -1;
var lastImageSwitch = 0;

function animate() {
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
    var time = new Date().getTime();

    //Switch to next slide after 5 seconds
    if(time - lastImageSwitch >= 5000) {
        curImage++;
        curImage%=images.length;
        ctx.drawImage(images[curImage], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.stroke(); //Stroke outline to smooth the clipping.
        lastImageSwitch = time;
    //Animated transition between slides
    } else if(time - lastImageSwitch >= 4500) {
        //Calculate alpha of next image in slideshow based on time until next image
        var alpha = 1 - ((5000 - time + lastImageSwitch) / 500);

        //Draw current image, then overlay next image with semi-transparency
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(images[curImage], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
        ctx.drawImage(images[(curImage + 1) % images.length], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        ctx.stroke(); //Stroke outline to smooth the clipping.
    }
}

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
```

EDIT: Attached code that I forgot
EDIT 2: Revised post after further investigation

Comment: There is no way someone can help you without seeing your code.

Comment: If something works on IE, kinda works on Safari and doesn't work on other browsers you gotta be having real black magic going on.